# Maximum power transferred by the source to the load

Tags: power, maximum-ratings

I am in the middle of doing this question however have reached an issue.
To find maximum power transfer I understand the equation is **P=I^2RL**
However the answer I get is 2.4w the answer should be 50W [image] The Answer i get for R2 is 15 ohms. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: How are you getting \$15\Omega\$ ?

Comment: Power transfered to what resistor, i.e. what is the load? R1 or R2 or R1 || R2 ?

Comment: I believe the load is R1||R2

Comment: So have you head about the *Maximum Power Transfer Theorem*? What does it say about the load resistance?

Comment: i get 15 by taking the total combined parallel resistance for R1 and R2 and equating to 10ohms

Comment: Yes, that's ok.

Comment: Well the power transferred from a supply source to a load is
at its maximum when the resistance of the load is equal
to the internal resistance of the source.

Comment: Yes, so your reasoning is ok ...as long as you are right about what is considered as the load resistance. If the problem considered only R2 as load resistance, the result would be different.

Comment: It is impossible to get 50W with the given schematic. A 12V supply with a 10 ohm internal resistance, when shorted, would supply (to it's own internal resistance) 15W of power. Since increasing the output resistance would only decrease current, you can never have the powersupply burn up more power, hence it's never going to deliver 50W

Comment: the other options available are 200,40,5 and 50w all are not near my answer

Comment: On the marking scheme it just states 50w

Comment: Maybe that's just to confuse those students who have no clue at all. BTW if they ask for resistance the options should have a unit (Ohm).

Comment: @Curd tempted to just continue my life without solving to be honest

Comment: The power provided by a power supply is it's current by it's voltage. The maximum current you can get out of it is by shortening it - `I=12V/10ohm = 1.2A`. So the maximal theoretical power the ideal source is providing is `1.2A x 12V = 14.4W`. So everything above this is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

I think you got many good comments -- especially on the impossibility of getting \$50\:\textrm{W}\$ dissipation anywhere in that circuit no matter how you look at it -- so long as you keep that \$r=10\:\Omega\$ present. I don't know where you got your suggestion for power dissipation from. But it doesn't make any sense. I'm hoping it is just your own misinterpretations and nothing other than that.

Assuming that dissipation value you have provided here is totally bogus, the question might instead be one of these:

1. What should \$R_2\$ be to maximize power in \$R_2\$? Here, Thevenize \$r\$ and \$R_1\$ to get an effective \$7.5\:\Omega\$ series resistance and, in that case, the answer is the obvious \$R_2=7.5\:\Omega\$ and the power will be \$2.7\:\textrm{W}\$ in \$R_2\$, \$675\:\textrm{mW}\$ in \$R_1\$ and and \$3.375\:\textrm{W}\$ in their combination.
2. What should \$R_2\$ be to maximize power in the combination of \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$? Here, you want the parallel combination of \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$ to be the obvious \$10\:\Omega\$, so \$R_2=\frac{30\:\Omega\cdot 10\:\Omega}{30\:\Omega-10\:\Omega}=15\:\Omega\$ and the power will be \$2.4\:\textrm{W}\$ in \$R_2\$, \$1.2\:\textrm{W}\$ in \$R_1\$ and and \$3.6\:\textrm{W}\$ in their combination.

Note that the dissipation is higher in \$R_2\$ in example 1, but that the total dissipation is lower. And that the total dissipation is higher in example 2, though the dissipation in \$R_2\$ is now less.

I can't come up with any other reasonable interpretations that assume the schematic as you gave it and the general idea of "maximizing" dissipation of something by adjusting the value of \$R_2\$. (Though you could maximize the power source's dissipation by simply shorting \$R_2\$, I suppose.)

I do think there may be just a tad bit of confusion in the way you write your own answer. You write that you get \$R_2=15\:\Omega\$ and also that the power dissipation is \$2.4\:\textrm{W}\$. Sure. But in this optimization case you are supposed to be maximizing the *total* dissipation so it would likely be wrong to then point out the dissipation only in \$R_2\$ as an answer. If maximizing the total dissipation, then it probably is the total dissipation you could also be calculating and discussing.